# Why is the quick sound of "took" like "chee"?

Tags: pronunciation

[Track source](http://www.kekenet.com/video/201612/482272.shtml)

> **It took me** nearly 20 minutes to go through the browser History on your
>   computer to see what movie times you looked up.

I can only hear

> It chee me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"took" does never sound like "chee" when spoken by an experienced English speakers (native or not).

Depending on the speaker, it may sound as [chook], but not [chee].

---

Other words have this property, e.g.:

> two -> [too] which can sound like [choo]

---

[ch] is the initial sound in "children" or "champion"

[oo] is long [u]

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of UK English, notably urban, you will hear a "t-y" pronounced as "tch", in a word like "boatyard" or a phrase "... at you ...".

Most commonly though:

- What are you up to?

Can degrade when said quickly:

- "What you up to?"  Can sound like "Whatchoo up to?"
- "What are you doing?" Can sound like "Cha doin?"

It is certainly very informal and not standard pronunciation.

This is sometimes spelled *wotcha* (OED has *watcha*) and on its own can be used as a colloquial greeting (I believe only in SE England) and you can hear:

- George: Wotcha Bert.
- Bert: A'right George.

Meaning approximately "Hello" and "How are you?" (Are you alright?)

It can even get as short as a nod of the head and "Tcha!"